# Cant open connection with phpmyadmin for new database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Try to open connection to phpmyadmin with this code: (have all time same issue - don't see NEW database !

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "srinivas";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly goes wrong how, and what error messages you are getting?

Comment: Try outputting the actual error from `mysql_connect_error()`. Note that `mysql_*()` is deprecated. You should use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` for new code.

Comment: If you are completely new to mysql, I recommend just using mysql for now. Once you're framilliar, just look up mysqli and learn some on that. That's what I had to to, and because I already knew mysql, it was easier. 

To answer your question, we need more specific things. I'm guessing that you created a database with PHPMYADMIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odviously, you have something right with mysql if you're already using PHPMyAdmin. We won't worry about that for now.

I would use better catches for your code. I noticed that you have the same error message for both scenarios. Such a simple like, such as this would help:

```
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops, something went wrong WITH LOGIN");
```

if you feel like getting more techincal, do this:

```
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops, something went wrong: " . mysql_error());
```

The last one will tell you basically exactly what's wrong here.